# Compare two files and update one with other in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have two files which are having same key column and based on that I have to update one file with other. Could you please help me to write logic for this in shell script?

Example:

src file:

```
+-------+-------+
|call_id|call_nm|
+-------+-------+
|    100|     QC|
|    105|     XY|
|    110|     NM|
|    115|     AB|
+-------+-------+
```

lkp file:

```
+-------+-------+
|call_id|call_nm|
+-------+-------+
|    100|     QZ|
|    105|     XY|
|    106|     XZ|
|    115|     JQ|
+-------+-------+
```

In above example I have to match both the files and update `src_File` based on the value in `lkp_file`. We have key_column - `call_id`.

First check key_column and then update the value in src_file. The final output should be like this-

src file:

```
+-------+-------+
|call_id|call_nm|
+-------+-------+
|    100|     QZ|
|    105|     XY|
|    110|     NM|
|    115|     JQ|
+-------+-------+
```

You can see value of 100 & 115 have changed based on lkp_file values.

Comment: `diff` and `patch`?

Comment: Can you please write it on shell script?

Answer (score 1):

Try this(back up your original file before exec this command):

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]{3,3}|[A-Z]{2,2}' lkp | xargs -n2 | xargs -I {} bash -c 'o=$(echo {}); n=(${o}); id=${n[0]}; nm=${n[1]}; sed -i "s/\($id|\ *\).*|/\1$nm|/" src'
```

- `'[0-9]{3,3}|[A-Z]{2,2}'`: extract **id** and **nm**
- `xargs -n2`: create the pairs like **100 QZ**
- `-I {} bash -c`: handle the pairs to **id** and **nm** variable for `sed` command
- `"s/\($id|\ *\).*|/\1$nm|/"`: only suitable for your file format like **`|    100|     QC|`**, just replace the **nm** before **`|`**, or you could use the pattern what you want such as **`[A-Z]+`**

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk -F\| '{if(NR==FNR){a[$2]=$0}else{if($2 in a)$0=a[$2];print}}' lkp_file src_file
+-------+-------+
|call_id|call_nm|
+-------+-------+
|    100|     QZ|
|    105|     XY|
|    110|     NM|
|    115|     JQ|
+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting `awk` script:

#### `script.awk`

```
BEGIN     {FS = OFS = "|"} # set awk field seperator and output field seperator to |
NR == 1   {footer = $0} # read footer
NR < 4    {header = header ORS $0; next} # read and ignore header
FNR == NR {arr[$2] = $3; next} # read array from 1st file
$2 in arr {arr[$2] = $3} # update arra if found id in file2
END {  # output the formated array
  print header;
  asorti(arr,arrSorted); # sort array indexes in arrSorted
  for (i in arrSorted) { # for each element in sorted array
    if (arrSorted[i] == "") continue; # ignore empty element
    print OFS arrSorted[i] OFS arr[arrSorted[i]] OFS; # print current element
  }
  print footer;
}
```

#### running `script.awk`

```
awk script.awk src_file.txt lkp_file.txt
```

#### output:

```
+-------+-------+
|call_id|call_nm|
+-------+-------+
|    100|     QZ|
|    105|     XY|
|    110|     NM|
|    115|     JQ|
+-------+-------+
```

Notice the output is correct and sorted in `id` order.